# TextView and VideoView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview, android-videoview

I have a TextView inside a LinearLayout and a VideoView inside a LinearLayout.

The parent layout is a RelativeLayout that includes the TextView's linear layout and VideoView's linear layout.

Since I add the VideoView with FILL_PARENT, FILL_PARENT params (coz I want it to fill the screen in landscape mode), in some phones when I rotate to landscape, the VideoView fills the entire screen, and the TextView is not visible.

This happens only in certain phones, and only in landscape mode.

I have tried setting a top padding for the VideoView's linear layout, but it looks like the padding should be different for different phones. For eg: a top padding of 10 works on a myTouch but not on Droid.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Hey Chris,

I am just working on something similar...but I have a problem that my TextView is placed right over the VideoView...I would like to separate both views so that first there is the VideoView and then comes the TextView...if you managed to do that could you maybe help me out here that would be great thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using FILL_PARENT you can use WRAP_CONTENT and then set the android:layout_gravity.  If you set the android:layout_gravity on the VideoView to 1 and don't set the android:layout_gravity of the TextView then it will show the TextView at it's correct height and then fill the rest with the VideoView.  If you show your layout xml I can give you a more specific example.

-- Edit: My bad I meant layout_weight

Comment: I thought layout_gravity was set to constants like Gravity.TOP, Gravity.LEFT etc. What does the value 1 mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right. It's not layout_gravity. It's layout_weight